# Sitecore Experience editor ribbon controls are not loading for specific content author user

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8.1

When opening any of the page in sitecore edit or preview mode the sitecore ribbon bar controls are not showing and instead its showing the below error (inside iframe only). the page components are getting loaded. This is happening specifically to a content author user and not for other content author users. please clarify whether there is any problem in users details.

Server Error in '/' Application.

---

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Client.Pipelines.Search.SearchContentSearchIndex.Process(SearchArgs args) +4314
   (Object , Object[] ) +73
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +468
   Sitecore.Search.XpathQuerySearcher.SelectItems(String query, Database database) +245
   Sitecore.Data.Database.SelectItems(String query) +80
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Commands.OpenMyItems.GetHeader(CommandContext context, String header) +178
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.FillParamsFromCommand(CommandContext commandContext, RibbonCommandParams ribbonCommandParams) +97
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.GetCommandParameters(Item controlItem, CommandContext commandContext) +78
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderSmallButton(HtmlTextWriter output, Item button, CommandContext commandContext) +77
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderButton(HtmlTextWriter output, Item button, CommandContext commandContext) +633
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderChunk(HtmlTextWriter output, Item chunk, CommandContext commandContext) +343
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderChunk(HtmlTextWriter output, Item chunk, CommandContext commandContext, Boolean isContextual, String id) +243
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderChunk(HtmlTextWriter output, Item chunk, CommandContext commandContext, Boolean isContextual) +160
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderChunks(HtmlTextWriter output, Item strip, CommandContext commandContext, Boolean isContextual) +419
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderStrips(HtmlTextWriter output, Item ribbon, Boolean isContextual, ListString visibleStripList) +1857
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderStrips(HtmlTextWriter output, Item defaultRibbon, Item contextualRibbon, ListString visibleStripList) +161
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) +746
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +78
   Sitecore.Web.HtmlUtil.RenderControl(Control ctl) +79
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.WebEditRibbonForm.RenderRibbon(Item item) +684
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.WebEditRibbonForm.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +1172

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +128
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +142
   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj) +89
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +597
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3785

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3429.0

Answer (score 0):

It seems the master db has not been indexed and hence the "my items" and editor ribbon bars are not loaded.

After doing the indexing the issue is resolved and i can able to see the editor ribbon bar.